# FileNotFound error in AWS Glue job, when json file path is fetched

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using aws Glue job to call python script in a S3 location. I am able to create job and run it through python code from local machine using boto3.
The script file in S3 has following code as sample shown below:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import json


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "RAW_DATA", "MAPPING_JSON"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

input_csv = args['RAW_DATA']

df = spark.read.csv(input_csv, header=True)
df.show()

mapping_json_path = args['MAPPING_JSON']
with open(mapping_json_path) as json_mapping_file:
    json_mapping_data = json.load(json_mapping_file)
```

Here, job parameters are s3 file paths and both the files are present in same S3 bucket.

RAW_DATA = 's3://bucket-name/data/raw/raw_data.csv'
MAPPING_JSON = 's3://bucket-name/configs/mapping.json'

The issue is, I am able to read the csv file without any errors, but for json file I get `"No such file or directory: 's3://bucket-name/configs/mapping.json'"`

```
"Stack Trace": [
        {
            "Declaring Class": "<module>",
            "Method Name": "with open(mapping_json_path) as json_mapping_file:",
            "File Name": "/tmp/script.py",
            "Line Number": 29
        }
    ],
    "Last Executed Line number": 29,
    "script": "script.py"
```

Initially I thought permission issue as saw couple of similar issues in stackoverflow with the role assigned to job, but csv file has no issues being read. But still I provided S3adminaccess to role assigned but, same error.
Tried putting the json file in different folders as well(which doesnt make sense).
NOTE: S3 bucket has public access and policy in the role has "s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject" as allowed actions to the whole bucket.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
with open(mapping_json_path) as json_mapping_file:
    json_mapping_data = json.load(json_mapping_file)
```

With:

```
mapping_df = spark.read.json(mapping_json_path, header=True)
json_mapping_data = mapping_df.toJSON()
```

If you want it as a json array, you can do:

```
json_mapping_data = mapping_df.toJSON().collect()
```

To read multiple line json file, use:

```
mapping_df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(mapping_json_path, header=True)
```

It's worthy to say that in this case you will unnecessarily be doing a conversion from json->dataframe->json. The proper way to do it is to simply load the json file from s3.
Here is an example with boto3:

```
from boto3 import client

BUCKET = 'MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME'
FILE_TO_READ = 'FOLDER_NAME/my_file.json'

result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE_TO_READ) 
text = result["Body"].read().decode()
```

Comment: Hi feedy. Yes, I used boto3 library to read json from S3. I was considering it as normal file read and totally forgot I am trying to read from an AWS service . Thank you anyways.